# Reload values in form from MySQL after form submit

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, submit

I have HTML form linked with MYSQL database via PHP. If I submit this form, values will save in MYSQL database but not load into form. I see there old values so I have to refresh page to see desired values.
I would like to see new values at form submission.

*** I solved it when i put header("Location: edit.php?page=zakladni_udaje.php")  ( = same as form action) on THE END OF ISSET form submit, it worked fine but I cant print message about success or fail after submiting.

```
<?php
ob_start();
session_start();

?>
<form action="edit.php?page=zakladni_udaje.php" method="post">
<?php

$con = mysql_connect("localhost", "mairichovci", "ak41801") or die("Nelze se připojit k MySQL: " . mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("mairichovci") or die("Nelze vybrat databázi: ". mysql_error());

if($_SESSION['id'] > 0){

$profil_pomocny = mysql_query("SELECT * from profil where id=".$_SESSION['id'], $con);
$profil = MySQL_Fetch_Assoc($profil_pomocny);

$or_pomocny = mysql_query("SELECT * from osobaky where id=".$_SESSION['id'], $con);
$or = MySQL_Fetch_Assoc($or_pomocny);

$zobraz_pomocny = mysql_query("SELECT * from zobraz where id=".$_SESSION['id'], $con);
$zobraz = MySQL_Fetch_Assoc($zobraz_pomocny);


$id = $_SESSION['id'];
$fce = $_POST['fce'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$tel = $_POST['tel'];
$position = $_POST['position'];
$home = $_POST['home'];
$omne = $_POST['omne'];




if( isset ($_POST['uloz'])):



$sql = "UPDATE profil SET
fce = '$fce', email = '$email', tel = $tel, position = '$position', home = '$home', omne = '$omne' WHERE id = '$id'";

if (!mysql_query($sql)):
die('Chyba: ' . mysql_error());
else:
$message = "Údaje byly uloženy";
endif;



mysql_close();


endif;
echo '<div id="message">'.$message.'</div>';
?>



<table style = "margin-top: -1px" align="center" class="tabulka">
<tr>
<td width="40%">Funkce:</td>
<td><input type="text" name="fce" placeholder = "(např. Běžec - 800m, 1500m a delší)" maxlength="35" size="48" value="<?php echo $profil['fce']; ?>" class="vstupy" style="width: 350px"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" name="uloz" value="Ulož" class="tlacitko2" style="width: 350px; margin-left:4px"></td>
</tr>

</table> 
</form>

<?php
}
else{header("Location: prihlas.php");}
ob_end_flush();
?>
```

I appreciate every advice. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: use mysqli or PDO you are vulnerable to SQL injections

Comment: `$profil` is never defined ANYWHERE in your code, so of course you'll never get any values inserted into your form.

Comment: SAM: can you write short examples please? :)

MARC: $profil is defined on 15th row :)